# Change alternate cell backgroundcolor of empty table view cell

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have created a tableview controller programmatically in swift4. My view currently looks like this
[image]

I want to have alternate gray colors as marked in the image in unused table view cell. I could change alternate color of used table view cell. 
Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have your tried this in tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell:

```
if indexPath.row % 2 == 0 {
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
} else {
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
}
```

It worked for me. I hope this also works for you.

Comment: I tried this... it only works for the rows which has content.